# excel VBA can't get spinbutton value

Tags: excel, button, vba

I have several shapes (autoshapes, connectors, labels, spin buttons) in a worksheet, and want to write several parameters of each one into another sheet. But I can't get the spin buttons Value with the code below (the message reads: the object does not admit this property or method). However, if I replace `sShape.Value` by `SB_FR.Value` (SB_FR is the specific name of one of my spin buttons) the code works ok. Value property is different from others properies, like Top, or Width or Left?

```
dim sShape as Shape
i = 0
For Each sShape In Worksheets("sheet1").Shapes
    Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(i + 1, 1) = sShape.Name
    Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(i + 1, 2) = sShape.Top
    Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(i + 1, 3) = sShape.Left
    ss = Split(sShape.Name, "_")
    if (ss(0)="SB") then            'if the shape is a spin button 
        Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(i + 1, 4) = sShape.Value  'Here the problem
    End If
    i=i+1
Next
```

Comment: No answers. Anyway, if anybody cares, now is working. I replaced `sShape.Value` with `Worksheets("sheet1").OLEObjects("" & sShape.Name & "").Object.Value`. I still don't understand why the original code is not OK.

Comment: i was just typing the answer :) `shp.OLEFormat.Object.Value` once you have set the `Shp` to the spinbutton :)